# Mock testing clarification

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I need a clarification about mocking tests. In my particular scenario, I have to test a service, that has the dependency on the connecting module, the connector. Basically what connector does, is that it creates an instance of the service call that has to be made. I will demonstrate on the example.

```
public DataService(Connector connector) {
    this.connector = connector;
}

@Override
public ServiceData getWeatherData(String dataId) throws ServiceCommunicatonException {

    try {

        return connector.newGetWeatherDataCall().call(
                WeatherData.builder().withId(dataId).build());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServiceCommunicatonException(ERR_MSG);
    }

}
```

So the `connector.newGetWeatherDataCall()` returns the instance of the type `WeatherData`.

Now, in order to test the `Service`, I guess I would need to mock the `Connector`. Mocking the `Service` is probably pointless, because then I am not really testing it, right?

I tried mocking the `Connector` with something like this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    connector = mock(Connector.class);
}

@Test
public void getDataTest() {
    assertNotNull(service.getData("123"));
}
```

However, this is obviously wrong, because this gave ma `NullPointerException` because `WeatherDataCall` from this line: return

```
connector.newGetWeatherDataCall().call(
                    WeatherData.builder().withId(dataId).build()); was null.
```

So how should this be properly tested/mocked? It would be great with some code examples.

Comment: what is the return type of connector.newGetWeatherDataCall() ? name of the class

Comment: WeatherData. I have added that in my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Test
public void getDataTest() {
    WeatherData getWeatherDataResponse = Mockito.mock(WeatherData.class);
    when(connector.newGetWeatherDataCall()).thenReturn(getWeatherDataResponse);
    when(getWeatherDataResponse.call(Matchers.any(Class.class))).thenReturn(new ServiceData());
    assertNotNull(service.getData("123"));
}
```

**Explanation:-**

- You got null because you did not set the expected return value. Actually connector.newGetWeatherDataCall() returns null. This is because you did not use Mockito.when() to return your expected results.
- Second : In your case, a method on this return value is invoked so connector.newGetWeatherDataCall() should return a mock of WeatherData. And now you will set an expectation for weatherData.call(..) which will be ServiceData type.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thank you. In addition, is that a sensible test  to write for this scenario? I mean, I can't really check the returned values from the service call, because I mock it, and I don't really have an idea on what to test besides of the call result being not null. However, this is also a little funny to test, because you indeed set it to be not null. I am a little bit confused by the concept what exactly is being tested here.

Comment: getWeatherData(String dataId) is taking a parameter. So can set some for this dataId I should get this response. Also you can check for null values.

Comment: You are unit testing public ServiceData getWeatherData(String dataId) . All its dependencies should be mocked. It's like you are given some job and you are like a manager. If I want to unit test you, I will assume that your dependencies are working fine. Meaning it is known what output they will return for a particular input. Now I will test your correctness and evaluate(which is assert). Summary is assuming that your dependencies are returning results correctly as per their definition, is your current method doing its JOB...

Comment: it is difficult(or tricky) for you to understand because there is no business logic in this case.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it was satisfactory and worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set up the mock to throw an exception, which is useful if the catch clause does a bit more work.